# Scheduled Task Produces Too Many Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

In one of my ECS clusters I have a scheduled Fargate task that's meant to spin up 8 instances of it's given target. However, when the task procs it starts up waaayyyy more than 8 tasks. Sometimes as many as 50. Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen?

Details:

- Cron Expression: `cron(40 16 ? * 1-5 *)`
- Target Definition:
  [image]

Comment: well i was just validating your cron expression i have found that '?' can only be specfied for Day-of-Month or Day-of-Week and your cron expression is invalid because you have applied it for hour, can it be an issue ?

Comment: It's not a 'real' cron expression that's used for scheduled tasks. It's some bastardization that Amazon came up with. Format here: `cron(Minutes Hours Day-of-month Month Day-of-week Year)`. Thanks for the attempt though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might run into this problem in the future:

This problem occurred because we had too many tasks running the cluster. As of the writing of this answer AWS set of limit of 50 tasks running in a single cluster. Before the rule triggered there was already close to 50 tasks running. The rule would proc and would start spinning up new tasks trying to get to the desired number (8).

However, due to the limit it would never be able to get 8 because new tasks over the limit would just get shutdown. So it would keep trying, and keep trying, and keep trying to spin up tasks which led to there being a huge pending queue of tasks that would seemingly push (nearly) all of our tasks out of the cluster and we'd be left with way more tasks than we had asked for.

The solution: we just moved the scheduled task into a new cluster to avoid the 50 task limit.